# Impossible to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-20.04

I spent hours trying every single methods found on Internet, without success.
The server is on Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache behind CloudFlare, no certbot, no letsencrypt.
I added `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` (and many other versions) on `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf` as well as on the bottom of apache2.conf.
I added `SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Protocol "-ALL, TLSv1.3"` on the VirtualHost.
I put `Protocols All,-TLSv1.1,-TLSv1.2` on the bottom of /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
I restarted Apache2 and cleared CloudFlare cache many times.
I'm really starting to be out of options. Is there a sort of cache somewhere?
Could restarting the server solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare is the HTTPS endpoint for the connection from the browser. From there it connects with HTTPS to your server and forwards the traffic. The settings done at your server only affect the connection between Cloudflare and your server. It has no effect on the connection from the browser to Cloudflare.

Comment: So CloudFlare has no incidence for the TLS? This doesn't help me much to solve my TLS issue. In the past I was able to deactivate TLS1.0, but now it's impossible.

Comment: They do. They even [document it](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003205452-Using-Minimum-TLS-Version-in-Cloudflare-SSL-TLS)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I saw other TLS parameters but not that one. Thank you so much!